# Odd and even numbers function error when value is different than integer

Tags: php

I'm writing a code that takes three arguments and returns the sum of even integers.

```
function check($a, $b, $c){

    if($a % 2 == 0 && $b % 2 == 0 && $c % 2 == 0) {
        if(is_int($a) && is_int($b) && is_int($c)) {
            $d=$a+$b+$c;
            echo "The sum of even numbers is $d" ;         
        }
    }
}

$a=4;
$b=4;
$c=6;

check($a, $b, $c);
```

On this lvl, my code works.
When I try to type a string or a float number I get nothing for float and string.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
function check($a, $b, $c){

    if($a % 2 == 0 && $b % 2 == 0 && $c % 2 == 0){
        if(is_int($a) && is_int($b) && is_int($c)){
            $d=$a+$b+$c;
            echo "The sum of even numbers is $d" ;         
        }
    } elseif (is_string($a) && is_string($b) && is_string($c)){
        echo "Error, enter the correct variable type";
    }else{
        echo "Error, enter the correct variable type";
    }
}

$a="Cat";
$b=4;
$c=6;
check($a, $b, $c);
```

Comment: Well what do you think the modulo of `cat` is?

Comment: If you turn error reporting on you will probably get an error something like this reported `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string % int`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Basically because you do this line `if($a % 2 == 0 && $b % 2 == 0 && $c % 2 == 0){` before doing ANY of your Type checking it fails there

Comment: Your code checks _all_ of the inputs at once, and if _any_ of them fails, then so does your code. You'll get a similarly broken result if you feed it an odd number. Check the inputs individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the `is_int()` tests before the even number test. `$a % 2` will convert `$a` to a number, and a non-numeric string converts to `0`, which is even.

```
function check($a, $b, $c){
    if(is_int($a) && is_int($b) && is_int($c)) {
        if($a % 2 == 0 && $b % 2 == 0 && $c % 2 == 0) {
            $d=$a+$b+$c;
            echo "The sum of even numbers is $d" ;         
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error, enter the correct variable type";
    }
}
```